# Need help with exporting from Materialize

Tags: texturing

I created a bump map and a metallic map in a program called Materialize, but when I exported them to blender they looked 3d but actually are just flate planes. Also, the colors changed a bit. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgVRB.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program creates several maps - including a height map. Don't use it as a bump map. If you want to use bumps, get Materialize to generate a normal map for you (bump is a cheap cheat)
However if you want to use actual displaced geometry, use the height map, transfer it to a Displace Vector with a Vector -> Displacement node and plug it into the Displacement slot of your Material Output Node. 
There are a few more options you will want to consider, too long to explain them here, the keyword to google for is: true displacement subdivision.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I undesrtand what you want me to do but, correct me if I'm wrong, doesn't that just work in cycles? I am doing this project in eevee, Is it also possible to do here?

Comment: yes, displacement works only in Cycles. In Eevee all you can do is extract a proper normal map and use that. You can however use the height map with a displace modifier to approximate the true displacement.